# Nodejs: Changing single key value in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This has been asked before but I was not able to understand the answer. So I am asking again. This is the object I need to manipulate.

```
[ 
  "description": {
      "zh": "CDes",
      "en": "EDes"
  },
  "nutrition": {
      "zh": "CNutrition",
      "en": "ENutrition"
  },
  "brand_names": {
      "zh": "chineseBName",
      "en": "englishBName"
  }
]
```

When I send a put request to the url with the following raw code

```
{ 
   description: {
     "zh" : "chinese"
   }
}
```

it changes to

```
[
  "description": {
      "zh": "Chinese",

  },
  "nutrition": {
      "zh": "CNutrition",
      "en": "ENutrition"
  },
  "brand_names": {
      "zh": "chineseBName",
      "en": "englishBName"
  }
]
```

but i want to keep the "en": "EDes" as well. I have used $set as

```
if (req.body.description.zh !== "undefined"){
    const id = "{" + req.params + " }";
    var obj = {
        'zh' : req.body.description.zh
    };

    Product.update(id, {'$set': {
        "description.$.zh" : req.body.description.zh    
        }
    });
}
```

but it is not working. I need to do this for description, nutrition and brand_names.Someone please help. Thank you
 [This is the screenshot of the json I am getting after GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nIxr.png)

Comment: The JSON array you're trying to manipulate is not a valid array.

Comment: {
    
    "description": {
        "zh": "CDes",
        "en": "EDes"
    },
    "nutrition": {
        "zh": "CNutrition",
        "en": "ENutrition"
    },
    "brand_names": {
        "zh": "chineseBName",
        "en": "englishBName"
    },
    "names": {
        "en": "english"
    }
}
This is the exact object I am getting from get request.

Comment: Can someone please tell me answer? @Xatyrian why is it not a valid array?

Comment: Well, with the braces it is a valid JSON object but with the brackets, as you wrote in your question, it is not valid : a JSON array can only contain JSON objects. You would have to write : `[{ "description": { "zh": "CDes", "en": "EDes" }, "nutrition": { "zh": "CNutrition", "en": "ENutrition" }, "brand_names": { "zh": "chineseBName", "en": "englishBName" }, "names": { "en": "english" } }]`. The other part of your JSON objects are also not valid. I suggest you edit your question so we can have a better understanding of what you're doing

Answer (score 1):

If this is your object

```
var yourObject = [ 
  "description": {
      "zh": "CDes",
      "en": "EDes"
  },
  "nutrition": {
      "zh": "CNutrition",
      "en": "ENutrition"
  },
  "brand_names": {
      "zh": "chineseBName",
      "en": "englishBName"
  }
]
```

You can get the zh object by

```
  var obj = {
    'zh' : yourObject[0].description.zh
};
```

Your Initial object is an array

Comment: How do I update only "zh" part of the description without writing over "en" part of the description?

Comment: yourObject[0].description.zh = "New Value"

Comment: `yourObject is not a vliad JSON array ... As i said in one of my comments, you have to add braces inside your brackets because a JSON array can only contain JSON objects. I suggest you try [this validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to see that it is not valid.

Comment: @Xatyrian I have added the screenshot of the JSON in the question. Please have a look.